# Why is this code working I took from a textbook for GUI Python?

Tags: python, user-interface

Why isn't this working. This is straight from the text book. I'm getting an Attribute error saying self._area does not exist.

```
from Tkinter import *
import math

class CircleArea(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        """Sets up a window and widgets."""
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Circle Area")
        self.grid()

        #Label and field for radius
        self._radiusLabel = Label(self, text = "Radius")
        self._radiusLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self._radiusVar = DoubleVar()
        self._radiusEntry = Entry(self, textvariable = self._radiusVar)
        self._radiusEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        #Label and field for the area
        self._areaLabel = Label(self, text = "Area")
        self._areaLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self._areaVar = DoubleVar()
        self._areaEntry = Entry(self, textvariable = self._areaVar)
        self._areaEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        # The command button
        self._button = Button(self, text = "Compute", command = self._area)
        self._button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

        def _area(self):
            """Event handler for button."""
            radius = self._radiusVar.get()
            area = radius ** 2 * math.pi
            self._areaVar.set(area)

        def main():
            CircleArea(). mainloop()
    run = CircleArea()
    run.main()
```

Is it because the _area method is declared after it is called? That doesn't make sense why it wouldn't work using a down up programming technique. I'm really new to GUI just started learning. First chapter on GUI for class.

edit*: I'm expecting a window to pop up and have one Entry field for input for the radius of the circle. With a label Radius. And an output entry field for the results of the area of the circle based on the radius. and a compute button at the bottom which computes it.

And I just wanted to get used to typing the different commands and such. I haven't even been in the lecture for this yet. I was just seeing what this code would do and what it would look like. I typed it all out by hand if that makes you feel better.:P Instead of copy and pasting.

Comment: How working? How? Can you please describe the expected results and the obtained ones?

Comment: You get an error: "Attribute error saying self._area does not exist." My bad for not seeing it.

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac actually wow I'm sorry. I didn't realize that my question said why is this working... So actually you were right to comment that. I was so confused on why you asked how it was working but now I realize. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your indenting is wrong. `_area` and `main` are defined within `__init__`, which you don't want. Correct indenting is below (you don't need a `main` function).

```
from Tkinter import *
import math

class CircleArea(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        """Sets up a window and widgets."""
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Circle Area")
        self.grid()

        #Label and field for radius
        self._radiusLabel = Label(self, text = "Radius")
        self._radiusLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self._radiusVar = DoubleVar()
        self._radiusEntry = Entry(self, textvariable = self._radiusVar)
        self._radiusEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        #Label and field for the area
        self._areaLabel = Label(self, text = "Area")
        self._areaLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self._areaVar = DoubleVar()
        self._areaEntry = Entry(self, textvariable = self._areaVar)
        self._areaEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        # The command button
        self._button = Button(self, text = "Compute", command = self._area)
        self._button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

    def _area(self):
        """Event handler for button."""
        radius = self._radiusVar.get()
        area = radius ** 2 * math.pi
        self._areaVar.set(area)

run = CircleArea()
run.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh you are right Tim... Wow I feel dumb. Thank you very much for your attention to detail!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you miss an argument in your main method,you define a class CircleArea , but in python you know that, each method defined in class must have an default argument named 'self',so just try this
def main(self):
    CircleArea(). mainloop()
I think it will work as you wish :)